# Can IIS Apply any extra compression to application/x-proto-stream

Tags: iis, compression, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

We've got a massive amount of data coming from out asp MVC website via application/x-proto-stream. Dynamic compression is turned on but looking at the figures in charles it doesn't look like any compression is being applied to it.

Just wondering if there is anyway that we can apply compression to this data going across the line from IIS?

Comment: Is there an Accept-Encoding header on the request?

Comment: Yeah there is an Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate on the request

Comment: you could use some tool like Fiddler, Network Monitor, Process Monitor, Metabase ACL,
IIS failed request tracing. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/performance-issues/troubleshooting-iis-compression-issues-in-iis6-iis7x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably need to [add the mime type to system.webServer/httpCompression](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/iis-dynamic-compression-and-new-dynamic-compression-features-in/ba-p/773878).

Also, IIS can turn off dynamic compression if server is under load - it can be configured with the [dynamicCompressionDisableCpuUsage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpcompression/) option of system.webServer/httpCompression

Comment: The correct mime types have been added already. I'll try the dynamicCompressionDisableCpuUsage now